# Why won't this work as a delay?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

I'll start off by saying I'm very very new to coding, so please bare with me.

I'm doing an assignment where the task is to create a traffic light system, but blocking delays aren't allowed. I have looked into "blink without delay", but it seems that option would require me to create far too confusing and long code than is needed. So instead I used for, else and goto functions together since it was a lot simpler and cleaner, but I have heard goto isn't a preferred option,

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i = i + 1)
{
    break0:
    digitalWrite(Traffic_R, HIGH);
    long int CurrentMillis1 = millis();
    
    break1:
    if (millis() - CurrentMillis1 <= 250){
        digitalWrite(Pedestrian_R, HIGH);
        goto break1;
    }else{
        long int CurrentMillis2 = millis();
        
        break2:
        if (millis() - CurrentMillis2 <= 250){
            digitalWrite(Pedestrian_R, LOW);
            goto break2;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I made another way without goto function,

```
for(int Test1 = millis(); Test1 < 7500; Test1 + millis())
{
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
}
```

**TLDR**
So my question is, are either of these methods a "blocking method", like delay is? Also what are the pros and cons of each method? Also I can upload the code for the first method if needed. Thanks heaps in advance!

Comment: I really do not agree that this code is “simpler and cleaner”. The 1st solution is what you would call “spaghetti code” and does nothing more than “busy waiting” i.e. it will not allow you to do anything else while the delay is happening (just like a normal “delay()” would). The 2nd solution is also “busy waiting” but a bit cleaner code. The reason solutions like “blink without delay” exist, is because they allow your code to delay some things (for ex. turning on an LED in a specific rythm) while continuing with others (for ex. Checking for a button or handling I/O). Your code cannot do that.

Comment: TBH, you first solution looks ugly, both in terms of control flow logic and indentation. And as StarCat says, there is no difference between a busy waiting loop and using `delay()`. Your second solution does not work, mainly because `Test1` is not changed in the loop. -- Anyway, there is no need to call `digitalWrite()` repeatedly with the same arguments.

Comment: **[Try to avoid the use of ```goto```, it is said to be a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto)**

Comment: **Fun fact:** *(Here in Greece [i don't know if anywhere else too])* **we call ```goto``` as the "black sheep" of programming**

Answer (score 2):

Here I have a simple example of cycling over 3 LEDs with the same 'delay' for every LED.

```
void loop() {

  static unsigned long previousMillis;
  static uint8_t cycleCounter;

  if (millis() - previousMillis > 100) {
    previousMillis = millis();
    digitalWrite(LEDS_CENTRAL_PIN, cycleCounter == 0);
    digitalWrite(LEDS_LEFT_PIN, cycleCounter == 1);
    digitalWrite(LEDS_RIGHT_PIN, cycleCounter == 2);
    cycleCounter++;
    if (cycleCounter == 3) {
      cycleCounter = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
break1: 
if (something) 
  goto break1;
```

is basically a while loop - just more confusing to read.

---

> Also I can upload the code for the first method if needed.

You can upload it, of course. Personally I would mark you down for using `goto`.

---

> are either of these methods a "blocking method", like delay is?

Neither method literally blocks. The `delay` function blocks because it doesn't return until the time is up. Your loops don't block because you could conceivably do something else in the loop.

---

> I have heard goto isn't a preferred option

For a good reason. Do you think that, if you looked at your code again in a year, you would easily understand it? I have been coding for years and would have to carefully follow all the ways that the `goto` could jump around in unexpected ways.

At least with a `while` loop you have a well-defined start and end of the loop.